# UK Business Visa from India - Status Check

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I have recently applied for long term UK business visa (2 years) in India. Last time when I had applied for Muti Entry 6 months Business Visa, I had received a reference number to track the status online (The reference format was `CHAC/*****/***/***`). I used [this link](https://www.vfs.org.in/UKG-PassportTracking/ApplicantTrackStatus.aspx) last time for status update.

However this time I did not receive any Refrence Number neither did I receive any email confirming the receipt of the application form. Also the above given link to check the status has a disclaimer `"This tracking module is only applicable for applicants applying for Kenya and Nigeria"`

I wrote to VFS global and they confirmed back that application is under process at BDHC, however they did not answer anything around `how to track` and `how to get reference number`

Just wanted to check with experts here

1. How do I check the status of my application?
2. Is status check only a
       paid service now (some SMS stuff I opt last time with some fee,
       which I forgot to opt this time)
3. Is there any way to track the status based on the reference number
   generated (`GWF0********`) while submitting form at [new UKBI site](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/index)

Comment: Ok..I got my Visa few days back, I checked with the VFS team, they did mention  about the tracking stuff being removed. They informed that the site (and as well as VFS) is going through multiple changes but did not confirm anything around reintroducing the tracking module back.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you like.

Comment: @YVXS any chance you could add that comment as an answer? It might be useful to future people to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got my Visa after 15 Days, I checked with the `VFS team` in detail and they did mention about the tracking stuff being removed (didn't give a convincing answer thou). They informed that the site (and as well as VFS) is going through multiple changes and due to this few services are discontinued temporarily; but did not confirm anything around the time-frame for reintroducing the tracking module back.

Also few services have become location specific it seems, a Colleague of mine who had applied for UK visa from Mumbai(Western India) location informed me that he opted for `SMS facility` and was getting regular `SMS on the progress` of the application, however for `Chennai` location (Southern India) the `SMS service is also suspended`

My suggestion to new Applicants is to check with the `VFS team` on the `SMS facility` (paid service from VFS) to notify on the progress on the Visa Application. Unfortunately there is no other way currently available to check the progress status apart for the Paid SMS service

Comment: Hi i l have similar problem. Today 10 days completed but not getting any SMS(already opted this service) or mail. can you suggest me how i contact VFS?